# Selecting the mode if the mode occurs before the given date R

Tags: r, grouping

I have data in a long format and am trying to clean up my bmi data a little bit. There are sometimes more than 1 value offered for a single day for the same person. I am using a lot of different types of logic in a large ifelse statement to fix these inconsistent values. One of the pieces of logic I would like to use as a last resort is to impute the mode (there is 1 mode per person). But I can only use the mode if it occurs before or on the date of the BMI value- as epidemiologists do not like it when a value that has not occurred yet is imputed for an older date.
I think I need to use some sort of grouping statement. But I am unsure how to write it. Because I want the logic to look at all the BMI values for an individual that happen previous to and on the date of concern. But I want a return for all rows (rather than returning 1 aggregate per person).

The variable called "MRN" is the ID variable- one id per person. And I would like to use the variable called BMI3_round as the BMI value of concern to match with the mode.

```
BMIdf2<-structure(list(MRN = c(8271L, 8271L, 8271L, 8271L, 8271L, 8271L, 
9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 
9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 
9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 
9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 
9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 
9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 
9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 9997L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 
76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 
76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 
76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 
76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 
76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 76133L, 
76133L, 76133L), OBSERVATION_DATE = structure(c(18039, 18058, 
18086, 18102, 18128, 18494, 15747, 15817, 15845, 18134, 18152, 
18153, 18169, 18183, 18183, 18183, 18183, 18184, 18205, 18205, 
18205, 18205, 18205, 18205, 18205, 18205, 18205, 18214, 18226, 
18226, 18226, 18226, 18234, 18235, 18242, 18247, 18249, 18249, 
18249, 18249, 18267, 18288, 18288, 18288, 18288, 18310, 18330, 
18351, 18373, 18393, 18414, 18435, 18457, 18478, 18499, 18520, 
18541, 18541, 18541, 18541, 18716, 18716, 18716, 18716, 16762, 
16779, 16780, 16790, 16790, 16790, 16790, 16791, 16807, 16807, 
16807, 16807, 16821, 16835, 16868, 16869, 16874, 16877, 16881, 
16919, 16975, 17017, 17077, 17280, 17290, 17318, 17318, 17318, 
17318, 17326, 17326, 17326, 17326, 17331, 17331, 17331, 17331, 
17333, 17336, 17339, 17347, 17360, 17381, 17402, 17423, 17444, 
17465), tzone = "America/Denver", class = "Date"), BMI3_round = c(38, 
38, 38, NA, 38, NA, NA, 30, NA, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 28, 28, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 28, 29, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, NA, NA, NA, NA, 35, 
NA, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, NA, 34, 34, 35, 35, 34, 35, 34, 34, 33, 
NA, 33, 32, 33, 33, 34, 33, 30, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 32, 33, 33, 33, NA, 33, 33, 32, 31, 31, 31, 32, 31), BMI3_mode = c(38, 
38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33)), row.names = c(NA, 
-111L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
```

Again, I would like to see if the mode occurred in BMI3_round on or before the OBSERVATION_DATE for a given person. There is only 1 mode per person, while there are multiple BMI3_round values. And I want to check for each row. It can return either "TRUE" or the mode if the mode for a person occurs in BMI3_round on or before the OBSERVATION_DATE. I want it to be "FALSE" or NA if the mode does not occur in BMI3_round on or before the OBSERVATION_DATE for a person. So it will be a comparison- if the mode of a person present in BMI3_round before the OBSERVATION_DATE for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` functions.

The first step would be creating a record of the earliest occurrence of BMI3_mode in BMI3_round for each MRN:

```
library(dplyr)

date_earliest_mode = BMIdf2 %>% 
  filter(BMI3_round == BMI3_mode) %>% 
  {aggregate(list(earliest_mode=.$OBSERVATION_DATE), by = list(MRN=.$MRN), FUN=min)}
```

```
    MRN earliest_mode
1  8271    2019-05-23
2  9997    2019-11-26
3 76133    2016-03-14
```

(This may need adjustment if the mode doesn't occur in BMI3_round, which however presumably wouldn't happen if the mode was calculated on the data in BMI3_round).

Now, merge by MRN:

```
merged = merge(BMIdf2, date_earliest_mode, by='MRN')
```

```
      MRN OBSERVATION_DATE BMI3_round BMI3_mode earliest_mode
1    8271       2019-05-23         38        38    2019-05-23
2    8271       2019-06-11         38        38    2019-05-23
3    8271       2019-07-09         38        38    2019-05-23
4    8271       2019-07-25         NA        38    2019-05-23
5    8271       2019-08-20         38        38    2019-05-23
6    8271       2020-08-20         NA        38    2019-05-23
7    9997       2013-02-11         NA        28    2019-11-26
8    9997       2013-04-22         30        28    2019-11-26
...
```

Now, we can create the variable you want with `merged$earliest_mode <= merged$OBSERVATION_DATE`:

```
merged = merged %>% 
  mutate(mode_already_occurred = earliest_mode <= OBSERVATION_DATE)
```

A random sample of rows shows that when OBSERVATION_DATE is less than the earliest occurrence of BMI3_mode in BMI3_round, the variable is FALSE, otherwise it's TRUE:

```
    MRN OBSERVATION_DATE BMI3_round BMI3_mode earliest_mode mode_already_occurred
1 76133       2016-06-23         33        33    2016-03-14                  TRUE
2  9997       2019-11-05         29        28    2019-11-26                 FALSE
3 76133       2017-07-13         32        33    2016-03-14                  TRUE
4  9997       2020-08-04         28        28    2019-11-26                  TRUE
5 76133       2016-01-07         34        33    2016-03-14                 FALSE
```